# In Eclipse, is it possible to configure two console views to always show the output from the same applications?

Tags: logging, eclipse, console

For example,

I'm writing a server, whose logs I print to a console view. 
I'm also using testNG, whose logs I print to another console view.

I use the "pin" functionality on the server console, so while that's running there is no issue, as the testNG console output automatically goes to the view that isn't pinned.

But is there a way to tell eclipse "Only use this console view for server_app" and "Only use this console view for testNG", so I don't have to keep selecting which console outputs what information?

I have many situations where I'd like this functionality. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, as best I can tell this is not possible.